# Implement a string

Tags: vba, excel, interface, implements

I would like to make a class which looks like a `String` to VBA. That is, if I make a function with a string argument, and pass this object instead, I won't get any errors.

I thought `Implements String` would work, but apparently it's not even an option!

Why is it not possible, and is there any way to get the behaviour I'm after? (Of course I could just make my own `IString` interface and specify my functions to request that, but I don't want to do that)

---

I'm trying to make a file-selection dialogue, which I can pass to any functions that require string-filepaths as arguments. This would be a neat self contained way of retro-fitting file-selection to existing functions.

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible in VBA (but @Mat'sMug is your man!). Couldn't you pass a `String` property of your class?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, now my knowledge is a step further. (hope i didn't wake you up!)

Answer (score 2):

Because the `String` is not an "object" to VBA, as it is to other languages like Java or .NET. If you want custom behavior, I'd probably just create a custom VBA class that wraps a string, rather than implementing it, and return a `String` output, in similar vein to a string builder class.

Answer (score 2):

With credit to the awesome Chip Pearson (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx):

You can do this by exporting the .cls to a text file; editing it Notepad to add a default attribute; saving it; then re-importing it into VBA. Let's give you an example.

In a class module:

```
Property Get Value() As String
    Value = "Hello"
End Property
```

Then export the module. I called it Str.cls. I then opened this file in Notepad, and added the following line (as marked):

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Str"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Property Get Value() As String
    Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0 ' <-- THIS is the line I added.
    Value = "Hello"
End Property
```

Save the file again in Notepad: then in the VBE, re-import it. Note however that the extra line (and all the other surrounding information) will NOT appear in the VBE, so it will look like your code hasn't changed at all. However you can now do the following (in a regular module):

```
Sub ReturnSringClass()
    Dim S As New Str
    MsgBox S
End Sub
```

Note now no property is required to be named with "S". It just behaves exactly like a string. You should be able to put a file selector in your class like this.

Comment: I love Chip Pearson's work - but saying the default member of a `Range` is it's `Value`, is taking a bit of a shortcut. The default member is a hidden member named `[_Default]` (you can see it in the *object browser* if you toggle hidden members), which *seems* to return the `Value`... but if it was consistently the case, then the default member would have been the `Value` property, not some hidden member. Clearly there's more to it than meets the eyes! ...and this is why default members are evil: you can't know what your code *really* does without digging into implementation details.

Comment: `Str` is a poor name for a class, as it shadows the built-in `Str` function. Also, `As New` will deliver you unexpected results with regard to initialisation, state and destruction.

Comment: Valid comments, Thunder - but I was knocking up a quick and dirty example to demonstrate the principle of editing the Attribute in a text editor, so used the shortest and most convenient method to do so. I don't expect the OP to copy my code line by line! Just to understand the core principle :)